# Find the Start and End Number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to use correct window function for my SQL problem.

I have the following table and I need find the  `start` and `end` numbers of continuous ranges.

Logs table:

```
+------------+
| log_id     |
+------------+
| 1          |
| 2          |
| 3          |
| 7          |
| 8          |
| 10         |
+------------+
```

Expected Result:

```
+------------+--------------+
| start_id   | end_id       |
+------------+--------------+
| 1          | 3            |
| 7          | 8            |
| 10         | 10           |
+------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is just to subtract an increasing value and then aggregate:

```
select min(log_id), max(log_id)
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over (order by log_id) as seqnum
    from t
) t
group by (log_id - seqnum)
order by min(log_id);
```

Comment: Any recommendation where I can do SQL exercises or practice, including advanced SQL fundamentals? any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: @Zorro . . . I have written books on the subject that recommend my books.

Answer (score 1):

You can do by using `row_number()`, try the following and here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2c5a3/1).

```
select
    min(log_id) as start_id,
    max(log_id) as end_id
from
(
    select
        log_id,
        log_id - row_number() over (order by log_id) as rnk
    from logs
) t
group by
    rnk
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a CTE-

```
With CTE AS(
select log_id,
log_id-row_number() over(order by log_id) as diff from logs)

Select MIN(log_id) as start_id,MAX(log_id) as end_id from CTE group by diff
ORDER by start_id
```